# Elixir : reduce enum over list of functions

Tags: elixir, reduce

I just wrote:

```
def transform(list_of_functions, elem) do
  Enum.reduce(list_of_functions, elem, fn func, res when is_function(func) -> func.(res) end)
end
```

To be called like:

```
transform([
  &(2*&1),
  fn x -> x % 3 end,
  &Integer.to_string/1
], 5) # "1"
```

But it feels so elementary that I'm wondering if such function exists in Elixir itself. I would have expected `Enum.transform/2` but it doesn't exist. :( Does it with another name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is counter-idiomatic in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir). We usually use pipe operator [`|>`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#%7C%3E/2) for that.

*Sidenote:* `%` is not an operator to perform modulo division, btw, [`rem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#rem/2) is.

```rb
5
|> Kernel.*(2)
|> rem(3)
|> Integer.to_string()
#⇒ "1"
```

Of course, if needed, that might be written in `foldl` notation.

```rb
Enum.reduce([
  &(2*&1),
  &rem(&1, 3),
  &Integer.to_string/1
], 5, & &2 |> &1.()) 
#⇒ "1"
```

But still, elixir is not haskell, carrying functions is not how idiomatic code is being written.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I get your point. I shall change the way I wrote this code.